# Is it possible to enable MFA for the guest users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have created guest users in my Azure AD tenant by sending invitations via email following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal.

The guest users are added to my tenant once they accept the invitation.
Now I have assigned some applications to the guest users that they can access.

To enhance the security, I want to enable two-factor authentication for the guest users when they are accessing the application.
**Is it possible to enable MFA for the guest users? If yes, can anyone guide me with the steps**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to enable MFA for guest users.**

To achieve your requirement, please follow the below steps:

- Make sure whether you have **`Azure AD premium P1` or `P2 license`** which is necessary to *create conditional access policy.*
- To create conditional access policy,
  ***Go to Azure portal -> Azure Active directory -> Security -> Conditional access -> Policies -> New policy.***

[image]

[image: image2]

In Grant tab, Select **"Grant access"** and Check mark **"Required Multi factor authentication".** Enable policy by selecting it **On** and **Create**.

[image]

***I have tried in my environment***, after creating policy I signed in as a guest user from **Incognito window** and it prompted for **two factor authentication** like below:
[image]